# how to clear browser cache in asp.net/javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my program i need to handle with many images.I have to change images dynamically within the page. after change the images i need to refresh the page by clear browser cache.

is there any method to clear cache or event for getting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> event in javascript or c# by a separate refresh button click. Here I cannot use browser refresh button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot clear browser cache.the only idea is declare a session variable in c# code in page load and set its value is 1 at the very first time

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
Session["refresh"]="1"
}
```

you will need to set session variable in image upload button event Session["refresh"]="1"
then create a refresh button .in the button event do the following
 thats all.after completeing your upload,click on the refresh button.then it work as ctrl+f5 button.if you not set the session value 0 in refresh button event the last event is again takesplace.if you enter a value in database,the same task takesplace if you not set session variable 0.

```
   if(Session["refresh"].ToString()=="1")
   {
      Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>locaton.reload()</script>");
      Session["refresh"]="0";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

No. You can set expiration time to zero, but this can be overridden in browser preferences.

If you really need that the browser don't cache image, generate a random number and place it in the url